# Why cargo build can’t offer colorful error messages?

Tags: rust

In PowerShell, If I use “rustc” to compile “main.rs”, I could get grammar error messages in colors.

With “cargo build”,I only could get 2 colorful words “Compiling...””error...” with unicolor grammar error messages .

What wrong with the color?

Comment: Is it possible that your `main.rs` was compilable for `>cargo build` and not for  `>rustc` ?

Comment: The point is, it shouldn't print as `Finished` if it can't compile successfully. Is it error messages or warnings ? It may be more clear if you add screenshots to the question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I got another colorful word: red”error”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of programs that can output color, `rustc` detects if its output goes directly to a console or is redirected to a file. This is because color is usually generated by inserting special control characters in the output and those characters would pollute the file.

When `cargo` calls `rustc`, it intercepts its output and prints it in one go at the end, so that it can call `rustc` in parallel multiple times without their output being mixed-up. Unfortunately, this hides the fact that it is running in a console from `rustc` (since strictly speaking it isn't: it's running into `cargo` which is itself running in the console).

`rustc` has a command-line argument to force color even when not running in a console: `--color always`. On Linux, `cargo` enables this argument when it calls `rustc`, so error messages do have color. I suspect that PowerShell handles color differently from Linux consoles which prevents the same from working for you. You can try it by setting the [`RUSTFLAGS` environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) to `--color always` before calling `cargo build`.

Comment: Follow your advice,I got another error: Option ’color’ given more than once

Comment: This means that `cargo` was already giving it properly. So I guess this is a limitation of PowerShell.

Comment: I got it. It’s wrong with PowerShell 5 on win7. Back to win10, I got the excepted colors. Thank you for your kindnesses and patience.